# Arrays, vectors and matrices in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, linear-algebra, linear-programming

I'm trying to use TFOCS to solve linear programming problems. In the documentation, the "Constraint matrix" is an array of vectors:

```
val A = sc.parallelize(Array(
    Vectors.sparse(3, Seq((0, 0.88))),
    Vectors.sparse(3, Seq((1, 0.63))),
    Vectors.sparse(3, Seq((0, 0.29), (2, 0.18)))), 2)
```

Are `Vectors` equivalent to `Arrays` in Scala? I want to be able to transpose `A` and merge it with another vector (like the `.r_` function in `numpy`). I know that multi-dimensional arrays can be transposed, but is it also possible to transpose an array of vectors? Additionally, is there a `.r_` equivalent in Scala?

Comment: have you taken a look at breeze https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/wiki/Linear-Algebra-Cheat-Sheet

Comment: ND4s is another good option https://www.cpuheater.com/scala/linear-algebra-machine-learning-scala/
https://github.com/deeplearning4j/nd4s